# How to add a conditional breakpoint in Visual C++

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-c++, visual-studio-2005, breakpoints

I want to add a breakpoint condition to my code in VC++ Express 2005, so that the breakpoint only triggers if a local variable meets a specified criteria. e.g.

```
bool my_test(UIDList test_list) {
    foo(test_list);
    bar(test_list); // I have a breakpoint here, but only want it to trigger if test_list.Length() > 0
    print(test_list);
}
```

Having right-clicked on my breakpoint and selected "Condition..." I have found a dialog that appears to do what I want, however anything I try typing into the text field results in the following error:

> Unable to evaluate the breakpoint
>   condition: CX0052: Error: member
>   function not present

I tried the help documentation, but I couldn't find my answer. I'm hoping someone experienced in VC++ might be able to point me in the right direction...

I have previously tried upgrading to a more recent version of VC++ Express, but the project did not import cleanly. Due to the complexity of the project and my current time scales I can't consider upgrading as a solution at this point.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

use the DebugBreak(); function:

```
bool my_test(UIDList test_list) {
    foo(test_list);
    if (bar(test_list) /* or whatever check :) */) // I have a breakpoint here, but only want it to trigger if test_list.Length() > 0
        DebugBreak();
    }
    print(test_list);
}
```

Or you can always use assert(expression)

```
bool my_test(UIDList test_list) {
    foo(test_list);
    bar(test_list);
    assert(test_list.Length() > 0); // will break here
    print(test_list);
}
```

Answer (score 10):

VS does have some micro-evaluation engines- in variable watch windows, immediate window, break point conditions etc. I could never find decent documentation on them. As far as i can tell they are picky about methods they're willing to call, **but** they're also insensitive to access limitations.
So, you can probably rephrase your condition from

```
test_list.Length() > 0
```

to something like

```
test_list.m_nLength > 0
```

(or whatever your private length var is).

(EDIT) Just found [this msdn page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e0ysa1hs(VS.80).aspx) explaining what expressions the debugger can and can't handle.  So first, [indeed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0888kc6a(VS.80).aspx) -

> 'The debugger can access all class
>   members regardless of access control.
>   You can examine any class object
>   member, including base classes and
>   embedded member objects.'

And second, my guess regarding the failure to evaluate 'Length()' - it was probably inlined:

> 'A debugger expression cannot call an
>   intrinsic or inlined function unless
>   the function appears at least once as
>   a normal function.'

Answer (score 4):

The conditions in a breakpoint can't call methods as far as I know. So, what you need to do is to calculate the length before hand. Something like this.

```
bool my_test(UIDList test_list) {
 foo(test_list);
 int i = test_list.Length();
 bar(test_list); // I have a breakpoint here, but only want it to trigger if test_list.Length() > 0
 print(test_list);
}
```

Put a conditional breakpoint on the value of i here and you should be fine.