# Accessing 'cmath' functions in the Immediate Window of Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

In Visual Studio 2010 Express using the debugger I can enter member functions like:

```
?visc(alpha,i)  
8.2814899360436612e-005
?get_sign()
0.91513417241239037
```

into the Immediate Window and they work fine.
However if I try:

```
?sin(alpha)
?math.sin(alpha)
?cmath.sin(alpha)
```

I get `Error: symbol "math" not found` and so forth.  I have included **cmath.h** in the main file and use `sin`, `asin`, `cos`, `acos`, `atan2`, and `sqrt` throughout the code. How do I get these functions in the Immediate Window? I googled my question and found a request for this to be added in 2005 and examples using member functions.

Comment: I don't know much about VS, so this is a wild guess, but since `cmath` has its function in namespace std, does `std::sin(alpha)` work?

Comment: if I type std::sin(alpha) into the immediate window I get CXX0017: Error: symbol "std::sin" not found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like this isn't supported directly:
http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/283279/add-simple-maths-function-support-to-debugger-exp-sin-cos-sqrt

I'd think if you knew the right dll, though, you could use the just-barely-documented Context Operator to get it (this is the second time this week I've come across this guy's blog):
http://thetweaker.wordpress.com/2009/05/30/breaking-on-system-functions-with-the-context-operator/

An answer to a similar question:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/3032271/611672

Hope this helps.

Comment: So this is a correct answer.  I just need to find the dll that has the function I need.  Any ideas how to do that?  When I look at the loaded modules I see ntdll.dll, kernel32.dll, KernelBase.dll, msvcp100d.dll and mscvr100d.dll.  All fail directly except msvcr100d.dll which will take {,,msvcr100d}sin() and return <void>.  If I try to use a number such as {,,msvcr100d}sin(0.786) it returns Error: argument list does not match a function.  I know from math.h that sinl(_X) is what is actually called.  However msvcr100d does not have that symbol.  What am I missing?

Comment: I don't know. I tried to get sqrt yesterday. You might have to have symbols for the dll and get the compiler decoration just right. (My eventual goal was to get sqrt working from within a .natvis file, but I'm probably going to give up on that.)

I suppose if push comes to shove you can build your own dll and expose mySine and myCosine, but ouch.

A colleague said you should be able to set a breakpoint and step in the intrinsic function in disassembly and look at the call stack to get the mangled name. I got distracted before trying that.

Answer (score 0):

Only some of the exported dll functions are working in the visual studio immediate window. Some of the most common functions such as the sin, cos, pow, exp are not working. Here are a few tested working functions in visual studio 2012:

```
msvcp110d.dll!log(2.0)
0.69314718055994529
msvcr110d.dll!sqrt(2.0)
1.4142135623730951
msvcr110d.dll!_hypot(-2.0,1.0)
2.2360679774997898
msvcr110d.dll!_logb(-2.0)
1.0000000000000000
msvcr110d.dll!abs(-2.0)
2.0000000000000000
msvcr110d.dll!acos(-2.0)
-1.#IND000000000000
msvcr110d.dll!cosh(1)
1.5430806348152437
msvcr110d.dll!fabs(1)
1.0000000000000000
```